# how to avoid Fragments Overlap in android with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, navigation-drawer, preferencefragment

i am creating a application in which i am using preference Fragment with navigation Drawer my problem is i am created navigation Drawer and in which i am added some menu item in which i want to load the preference Fragment as a first element when the app loads.it is does as i don to display. when i am changing the options I-e.when i am changing the drawer menu options like second element the in the drawer menu fist view is not replacing with the second,it is overlapping an the first[image]

my navigation drawer xml is as follow

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.koteswara.wise.NavigationDrawerMainActivity" >

  <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_gravity="start" >
 <ListView 
     android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    tools:context="com.koteswara.wise.NavigationDrawerFragment" />
 </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

my preference fragment is like this

```
public class AutoAnswerPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { 
    private AutoAnswerNotifier mNotifier;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);
        mNotifier = new AutoAnswerNotifier(getActivity()); 
        mNotifier.updateNotification();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences();
        sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);


        }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() { 
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        super.onDestroy();
        }
    @Override 
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) { 
        if (key.equals("enabled")) { 
            mNotifier.updateNotification();
            }  
        } 

    }
```

my fragment class which is adding to load the PreferenceFragment is

```
public class AutoAnswarFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new AutoAnswerPreferenceActivity()) .commit();


    }
```

the navigation Drawer class in which show fragment method is

```
protected void showFragment(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new  AutoAnswarFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
             fragment = new Tab2();
            break;
        case 2:
            // fragment = new BhajanaFragment();
            break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            // mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            // mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            mTitle = mDrawer_title[position];
            // mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            // Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }


}
```

if i will call the fragment other than the preference Fragment like below it will works please help me

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

i am struggling to clear the solution for it please any body solve it and please tell me the solution .i will be the thank full please help me

Comment: im also looking a perfect answer for this, but not got yet. But i have done a little trick , i just put a white background color to my layout. problem solved.

Comment: i am using the frame layout in the xml is i need to make the background of frame layout to white

Comment: yes . i did that and temporarily solved it. but in real its not the right way.

Comment: change your tab2() fragment background also to any color .

Comment: if you find any solution for that please let me know

Comment: Yes . of course. I will share it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on so many days of research and searching on the web i have found a solution its working fine for me for the above problem there is a link on the web as http://www.michenux.net/android-preferencefragmentcompat-906.html in this i found a sample apk and a source code regarding the apk . as this apk has a functionality as it solves my problem . i cleared the errors of the source code which will comes when you import and after that i added the library to my project. I used the PreferenceCompatFragment rather than PreferenceFragmentCompat, it solved my problem if anybody needs help it may help them also so that i am posting my solution to the above problem. and i thank who are all helped me who and all given some valuable suggestion for the above problem.
The below class  below i have used instead of PreferenceFragmentCompat of v7 support library

```
public abstract class PreferenceCompatFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final int FIRST_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int MSG_BIND_PREFERENCES = 1;
    private static final String PREFERENCES_TAG = "android:preferences";
    private boolean mHavePrefs;
    private boolean mInitDone;
    private ListView mList;
    private PreferenceManager mPreferenceManager;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {

                case MSG_BIND_PREFERENCES:
                    bindPreferences();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    final private Runnable mRequestFocus = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mList.focusableViewAvailable(mList);
        }
    };

    private void bindPreferences() {
        PreferenceScreen localPreferenceScreen = getPreferenceScreen();
        if (localPreferenceScreen != null) {
            ListView localListView = getListView();
            localPreferenceScreen.bind(localListView);
        }
    }

    private void ensureList() {
        if (mList == null) {
            View view = getView();
            if (view == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Content view not yet created");
            }

            View listView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            if (!(listView instanceof ListView)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class");
            }

            mList = (ListView)listView;
            if (mList == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'");
            }

            mHandler.post(mRequestFocus);
        }
    }

    private void postBindPreferences() {
        if (mHandler.hasMessages(MSG_BIND_PREFERENCES)) {
            mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_BIND_PREFERENCES).sendToTarget();
        }
    }

    private void requirePreferenceManager() {
        if (this.mPreferenceManager == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("This should be called after super.onCreate.");
        }
    }

    public void addPreferencesFromIntent(Intent intent) {
        requirePreferenceManager();
        PreferenceScreen screen = inflateFromIntent(intent, getPreferenceScreen());
        setPreferenceScreen(screen);
    }

    public void addPreferencesFromResource(int resId) {
        requirePreferenceManager();
        PreferenceScreen screen = inflateFromResource(getActivity(), resId, getPreferenceScreen());
        setPreferenceScreen(screen);
    }

    public Preference findPreference(CharSequence key) {
        if (mPreferenceManager == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return mPreferenceManager.findPreference(key);
    }

    public ListView getListView() {
        ensureList();
        return mList;
    }

    public PreferenceManager getPreferenceManager() {
        return mPreferenceManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getListView().setScrollBarStyle(0);
        if (mHavePrefs) {
            bindPreferences();
        }
        mInitDone = true;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Bundle localBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(PREFERENCES_TAG);
            if (localBundle != null) {
                PreferenceScreen screen = getPreferenceScreen();
                if (screen != null) {
                    screen.restoreHierarchyState(localBundle);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        dispatchActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
        mPreferenceManager = createPreferenceManager();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater paramLayoutInflater, ViewGroup paramViewGroup, Bundle paramBundle) {
        return paramLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.preference_list_content, paramViewGroup, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        dispatchActivityDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        mList = null;
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRequestFocus);
        mHandler.removeMessages(MSG_BIND_PREFERENCES);
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
        PreferenceScreen screen = getPreferenceScreen();
        if (screen != null) {
            Bundle localBundle = new Bundle();
            screen.saveHierarchyState(localBundle);
            bundle.putBundle(PREFERENCES_TAG, localBundle);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        dispatchActivityStop();
    }

    /** Access methods with visibility private **/

    private PreferenceManager createPreferenceManager() {
        try {
            Constructor<PreferenceManager> c = PreferenceManager.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Activity.class, int.class);
            c.setAccessible(true);
            return c.newInstance(this.getActivity(), FIRST_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private PreferenceScreen getPreferenceScreen() {
        try {
            Method m = PreferenceManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("getPreferenceScreen");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            return (PreferenceScreen) m.invoke(mPreferenceManager);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void setPreferenceScreen(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen) {
        try {
            Method m = PreferenceManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setPreferences", PreferenceScreen.class);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            boolean result = (Boolean) m.invoke(mPreferenceManager, preferenceScreen);
            if (result && preferenceScreen != null) {
                mHavePrefs = true;
                if (mInitDone) {
                    postBindPreferences();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void dispatchActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            Method m = PreferenceManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("dispatchActivityResult", int.class, int.class, Intent.class);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(mPreferenceManager, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void dispatchActivityDestroy() {
        try {
            Method m = PreferenceManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("dispatchActivityDestroy");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(mPreferenceManager);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void dispatchActivityStop() {
        try {
            Method m = PreferenceManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("dispatchActivityStop");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(mPreferenceManager);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    private void setFragment(PreferenceFragment preferenceFragment) {
        try {
            Method m = PreferenceManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setFragment", PreferenceFragment.class);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(mPreferenceManager, preferenceFragment);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public PreferenceScreen inflateFromResource(Context context, int resId, PreferenceScreen rootPreferences) {
        PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen ;
        try {
            Method m = PreferenceManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("inflateFromResource", Context.class, int.class, PreferenceScreen.class);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            preferenceScreen = (PreferenceScreen) m.invoke(mPreferenceManager, context, resId, rootPreferences);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return preferenceScreen;
    }

    public PreferenceScreen inflateFromIntent(Intent queryIntent, PreferenceScreen rootPreferences) {
        PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen ;
        try {
            Method m = PreferenceManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("inflateFromIntent", Intent.class, PreferenceScreen.class);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            preferenceScreen = (PreferenceScreen) m.invoke(mPreferenceManager, queryIntent, rootPreferences);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return preferenceScreen;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure the root layout of all your fragments are having

android:background="@color/your_favorite_color"

In that way they will be hiding other fragments below.

Comment: Thanks, T double, glad to help you, so, please vote my suggestion.